# MPEG-4 format to mp4v

Tags: video, conversion, mp4

I have two mp4 files, one is in MPEG-4, other is in mp4v.
I was able to convert mp4v to MPEG-4, but is it possible to convert mpv4 to MPEG-4 ?

Why is it that whatsapp takes one MPEG-4 as video and mp4v as gif ?

[Info about files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NfUU.png)

Comment: MPEG-4 is an collect of 31 different standards that specify several codes, containers an encapsulation methods. On such standard (part 14) is the mp4 container format. mp4v is a codec (part 2). Basically you just asked how to convert mpeg-4 4 to mpeg-4. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4#MPEG-4_Parts

Comment: @szatmary so am I not able to convert the mpeg-4 4 or even gif file to mp4v ? Is there no way to get something like short gif in mp4 format to mp4v ?

Comment: You can convert from any format to any format. Mpeg-4 does not describe one format however, It describes many.